# unable to run the python script having "requests" module

Tags: python, python-requests, python-3.8

I'm using linux Debian where Python 2.7.9 is the default version. I installed python3.8 to run my `script.py` that has "import requests" module.

On running, it says import requests:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

In order to install manually, the "requests" module in linux, I installed the latest OPENSSL 1.1 version. but still no luck.

`pip3.8 install requests` gives me:

> pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL

However the ssl module in Python is not available. Collecting requests. Any available solution to install requests module and there by overcome this error?

Comment: how did you install python and pip? did you use `apt` or did you build and install from source?

Comment: build & installed. following are the commands used - wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.0/Python-3.8.0.tgz
tar xzf Python-3.8.0.tgz
cd Python-3.8.0
./configure --enable-optimizations --with-ensurepip=install
make altinstall

Comment: @SunnyPatel  tried the options. though the requests are getting installed now using apt-get install python-requests, still getting the same "No module named requests". Not sure under which python version these requests are getting installed. any insights to check that?

Comment: Did you check if `pip` has the module installed?

Comment: @SunnyPatel it has installed in pip directory and not in pip3.8 list. as I said earlier I have 2 versions of python. I'm unable to manually install requests module in pip3.8 list as it throws the initial error stating SSL issue. I have openssl 1.1

Comment: I would have noticed that if your question had the code tags in it. I'll update.